react native maps on expo go display only gray background
this is my first react native app .I run my app with expo go development build on android studio emulator ,I use map from react-native-maps but it is only display a gray background with google icon this is the component:
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native'
import MapView, { PROVIDER_GOOGLE,Marker,Circle } from 'react-native-maps';
function Map() {
console.log('provider',PROVIDER_GOOGLE);

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <MapView
                provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
                initialRegion={{
                    latitude: 37.78825,
                    longitude: -122.4324,
                    latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
                    longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
                  }}
            >
            </MapView>
        </View>

    )
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
        height: 400,
        width: 400,
        justifyContent: 'flex-end',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    map: {
        ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
    },
});
export default Map;

according react-native-maps installation
I try to add API key to manifest file (android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml):
<application>
   <!-- You will only need to add this meta-data tag, but make sure it's a child of application -->
   <meta-data
     android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
     android:value="Your Google maps API Key Here"/>
</application>

create google_maps_api.xml in android/app/src/main/res/values.:
<resources>
  <string name="google_maps_key" templateMergeStrategy="preserve" translatable="false">(api key here)</string>
</resources>

in app.json I add android.config.googleMaps.apiKey:"my-api-key".
i see in expo-docs that No additional setup is required when testing your project using Expo Go,so why the map is not display?

your google cloud console, remove any restrictions you have added for your api key and try again. Problem is not with your code.
